# Webservice XML Request Error

Tags: xml

As Per the schema definition from this url
[Service URL](http://www.con-way.com/XML/doc/RateRequest/#complexType_ItemType_Link03B55B68)

I Requested XML Like this, but am getting error when i send request to https://www.con-way.com/XMLj/X-Rate. How to pass ItemType Element?

```
<RateRequest>
<OriginZip country='us'>97006</OriginZip> 
<DestinationZip country='us'>33179</DestinationZip> 
<CustNmbr shipcode="S">883885</CustNmbr>
<ChargeCode>P</ChargeCode> 
<EffectiveDate>10/30/12</EffectiveDate> 

<Item> 
<CmdtyClass>775</CmdtyClass> 
<Weight unit='lbs'>667</Weight> 
</Item> 

<ItemType>
<Quantity pkgtype='PCS'>100</Quantity>
</ItemType>

<Accessorial>SSC</Accessorial> 
<Accessorial>DNC</Accessorial>   
<Accessorial>GUR</Accessorial> 

</RateRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from the schema definition, ItemType is not a valid child element of the RateRequest element. This will probably cause the error.

```
<xs:element name="RateRequest">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="OriginZip"/>
      <xs:element ref="DestinationZip"/>
      <xs:element name="CustNmbr" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:positiveInteger">
              <xs:attribute name="shipcode" type="ShipCodeType" use="optional" default="S"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element ref="ChargeCode" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="DiscountRate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="EffectiveDate" type="DateMMDDYYType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="4">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="CmdtyClass"/>
            <xs:element name="Weight" type="WeightWithUnitType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Accessorial" type="RatingAccessorialCodeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="7"/>
      <xs:element ref="TotalCubeVolume" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element ref="SIC" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="schemaVersion" type="SchemaVersionType"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I've looked up the suggested usage of the RateRequest xml on the conway site, and it seems the ItemType complex-type can't be used in any way in the request. The Item elements can however refer to a (pre-)defined item using the CmdtyClass type reference. This CmdtyClass type is also used in the ItemType complex-type when an item is being defined.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, Even when i add below the RateRequestELement, am getting the same error.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some usage information I've found on the con-way site.